# How to implement the Location function of User Plus+ Plugin from Rainlab?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I've implemented the Country Select Form and State Select Form in my frontend from the Location Plugin. The values get populated according to the backend settings of Location. But if I click on register, the country and state are not saved.

first i thougth it's a fillable problem because no errors are thrown. Then I looked into the code an realized that the documentation of the Location Plugin states that the Behavior Controller adds two new relation to the implemented model (state and country). Looking at the code example for the location plugin i noticed that the select form fields are named 'country_id' and 'state_id'. I have changed them to country and state so the usermodel picks up the relation created by the Location Behavior but still no luck. The fields aren't saved. What am I doing wrong?

partial site/country-state-horizontal.htm

```
 {% set countryId = countryId|default(form_value('country')) %}
 {% set stateId = stateId|default(form_value('state')) %}
 <div class="uk-margin">
     <div class="uk-margin">
         <label class="uk-form-label" for="accountCountry">{{ 'Land'|_      }}</label>
         <div class="uk-form-controls">
             {{ form_select_country('country', countryId, {
             id: 'accountCountry',
             class: 'uk-select',
             emptyOption: '',
             'data-request': 'onInit',
             'data-request-update': {
             'site/country-state-horizontal': '#partialCountryState'
             }
             }) }}
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="uk-margin">
     <label class="uk-form-label" for="accountState">{{ 'Bundesland'|_      }}</label>
     <div class="uk-form-controls">
         {{ form_select_state('state', countryId, stateId, {
         id: 'accountState',
         class: 'uk-select',
         emptyOption: ''
         }) }}
     </div>
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**

partial snippets/intro.htm

```
    <form 
     data-request="onRegister"
     class="uk-form-horizontal uk-margin-large">
          <div class="uk-margin">
               <label class="uk-form-label" for="registerName">Vorname</label>
               <div class="uk-form-controls">
                    <input
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            class="uk-input"
                            id="registerName"
                            placeholder="Bitte deinen Vornamen eingeben" />
               </div>
          </div>

           <div class="uk-margin">
                <label class="uk-form-label" for="registerSurname">Nachname</label>
                <div class="uk-form-controls">
                   <input name="surname" type="text" class="uk-input" id="registerSurame" placeholder="Bitte deinen Nachnamen eingeben" />
                </div>
           </div>

 .....

           <div id="partialCountryState">
                {% partial 'site/country-state-horizontal' countryId=user.country_id stateId=user.state_id %}
           </div>

 .....

           <div class="uk-margin">
                <button type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary">Registrieren</button>
           </div>
```

Expected: Form saves the Ids for the User upon registration for country and state
Actual: Fields stay empty

Comment: can you also add details how you are saving your data to user model.

Comment: I edited the Code where I am calling the registration form... I use the regular user plugin methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read plugin and find out that its `general plugin` so to make it **compatible** to `users plugin` we need to **add some extra code there**.

> 1. Add needed fields in table ( manually )

we need to manually add `country_id` and `state_id` in to table `users`

you can add them by creating new version file from `builder plugin and apply that. make sure it stays`country_id and state_id`[ in your case you tried to change them if that so just revert back and add postfix`_id`]

```php
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\SoTest\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class Migration1013 extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function($table)
        {
            $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
            $table->integer('state_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        // Remove fields
    }
}
```

> 2. Now in your plugin's `boot` method add this code

```php
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\SoTest;

// ... 
use RainLab\User\Models\User as UserModel;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

    public function boot() {

      UserModel::extend(function ($model) {
        $model->implement[] = 'RainLab.Location.Behaviors.LocationModel';
        $model->addFillable([
            'country_id',
            'state_id',
        ]);
      });

    // ...
```

Now just try to save your data it should save `country and state` and to retrieve them you can use

```php
echo $userModel->country_code; // US
echo $userModel->state_code; // FL

echo $userModel->country_id; // 10 respective id
echo $userModel->state_id; // 22 respective id
```

### With User Plus(+) plugin installed

> Not sure with User Plus(+) plugin but I debugged and find some issue,  because of this commit https://github.com/rainlab/location-plugin/commit/6360a319f1e1e3eff8b6a43e85bdfdf3f84fbb58 `fillable is not working properly`.

So, We can try to add it manually again once more.

```php
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\SoTest;

// ... 
use RainLab\User\Models\User as UserModel;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

    public function boot() {    
      UserModel::extend(function ($model) {            
        $model->addFillable([
            'country_id',
            'state_id',
        ]);
      });
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Maybe I misunderstood something. I have the User Plugin installed. After that I installed the User+ Plugin. This automatically installed the Location Plugin and Notification Plugin. I've checked my database tables and confirmed that the country_id and state_id column was created by installing the User+ Plugin. The Location.Behavior also has the addFillable country_id and state_id included. Do I have to create a another Plugin and define it again?

Comment: ok let me check it with user+ plugin as i did not check that one and revert your back

Comment: actually i misunderstood that one user plus means addition to another plugin :) i will check it

Comment: Ok I checked but seems problem is little different , so can you try `With user Plus(+)` solution which I updated, we add `fillable` again and can you let me know it worked for you or not.